# How do I un-ignore a specific method on a templated class in SWIG?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I have a header file with a gazillion things in it and I need to call just a couple of them from Java - here is an example I cooked up (of course the real one is a monster and I cannot split it up as it is provided by a third party):

```
#ifndef _HIDING_H_
#define _HIDING_H_

template<class T> class SomeClassIWant {
public:
    void yupWantThis();
    T nopeDoNoWantThis();
};

class SomeClassIDoNotWant {
public:
    void definatelyDoNotWantToCallThisFromJava();
};

SomeClassIWant<int> createTheClassIWant();

#endif
```

I figured, therefore that [SWIG 3.0.2](http://www.swig.org) would do the job nicely for me so I created the following SWIG interface file:

```
%module hiding;

%ignore "";

%rename("%s") createTheClassIWant; 
%rename("%s") SomeClassIWant;
%rename(IntSomeClassIWant) SomeClassIWant<int>; 
%rename("%s") SomeClassIWant<int>::yupWantThis;

%{
#include "hiding.h"
%}

%include "hiding.h"

%template(IntSomeClassIWant) SomeClassIWant<int>;
```

And I ran swig (`swig -c++ -java hiding.i`) and listed the `*.java` files:

```
hiding.java
hidingJNI.java
IntSomeClassIWant.java
```

OK, so the ignore everything and un-ignoring what I want seems to have worked except there is one fly in the ointment...

The `IntSomeClassIWant.java` file has the following in it:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
 * Version 3.0.2
 *
 * Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
 * the SWIG interface file instead.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
public class IntSomeClassIWant {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected IntSomeClassIWant(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(IntSomeClassIWant obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
             "C++ destructor does not have public access");
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public IntSomeClassIWant() {
    this(hidingJNI.new_SomeClassIWant(), true);
  }
}
```

There is no **yupWantThis** method available to me - I *thought* I had unignored that with the line `%rename("%s") SomeClassIWant<int>::yupWantThis;` but it seems not.

Try as I might, I cannot figure out how to get this method visible - perhaps I need to do something in the `%template` line or something, I am flummoxed, so...

**How do I un-ignore a specific method on a templated class in SWIG?**

Answer (score 3):

It's not comprehensible research, but you can just reenable all entities named `yupWantThis`. This will include your method.

This should work:

```
%rename("%s") yupWantThis;
```

However, it will reenable all methods/classes named like this and i'm not sure if that works for you.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was hoping to be a bit more surgical and just enable the yupWantThis method on the class IntSomeClassIWant.  What you suggest could be a fine workaround though if I cannot do that (so +1).  I'll do it on my real code and see what pops up - perhaps I can get away with enabling all entities with a given name in the hope that what I enable has no duplicates.